# how to register time and machine name on open visual studio specific project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

i'am working on multiple projects using visual studio 2015 , 
is there are away auto register record in SQL SERVER database when i just open the 
project

DATABASE :

```
ID     | Machine Name | Project Name | Start On | Finish On
------ | ------------ | ------------ |  --------|  -------  
Cell   | Cell         |   Cell       | Cell     | Cell
```

i need to connect SQL SERVER and visual studio to projects i'am working on 
to register the project name and the hours i spent working on 
i tried to search about this topic but i did't found something useful

Answer (score 0):

How do you update your work time at this moment? And no, as much as I know you can't connect a SQL Table to update and record when you open a project.

But you could make yourself a little programm where you can choose a Project (DropDownControl) and start recording and as soon as you finished recording it will update it to your table.

Comment: I had done my personal one to done something like i want but its not perfect as i was hope to make it full automated